# Merge 2 consecutive elements in a List<string>

Tags: c#, generic-list

Suppose a List of strings `List<string> lst_fruits` contains the following elements:

```
[1] apple
[2] peach
[3] pine
[4] apple
[5] pear
[6] ...
```

I am looking for an existing method that does the task of combining #3 and #4.

I have considered copying the content of #4 into #3 and remove at #4, but I am wondering if there is a better solution.

Comment: There is no better solution for this. You know indexes, and know what to do with them.

Comment: If it is only 3 and 4, no there is no 'elegant' way to do it. If it were for example every 3rd and 4th; this would be different :)

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't one. Because if there was one, it would do the same procedure you're doing. And maybe a concat on your func is a + c and for another it's c + a or c + "FOO' + a, so it better leave it for the developer.

Comment: Please, do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose.

Comment: @Tigran Thanks. I thought there was an existing method for that, but couldn't find it. In retrospect, it's so easy it's a bit silly to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I went with this:

```
public static List<string> combine_list_elements(List<string> lst_original, int i, int j)
{
   if (lst_original.Count > i && lst_original.Count > j)
   {
       lst_original[i] += " " + lst_original[j];
       lst_original.RemoveAt(j);
   }
   else
   {
       throw new Exception("One of these 2 items does not exist in this list.");
   }
   return lst_original;
}
```

It's simple enough, not sure why I was looking for else.

Answer (score 2):

Are you happy with this approach?

```
lst_fruits =
    lst_fruits
        .Take(2)
        .Concat(new []
        {
            String.Join("", lst_fruits.Skip(2).Take(2))
        })
        .Concat(lst_fruits.Skip(4))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: for the simple task of merging two elements into one, I would say this is just obfuscating the code.. This is really not readable IMO..

Comment: +1 for a workable solution, but I agree with Default, it's less readable than the alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
    lst_fruits[2] = string.Concat(lst_fruits[2], " ", lst_fruits[3]);
    lst_fruits.RemoveAt(3);
```

The list indexes in your example should start at zero, also.
This is the simplest way to handle this, even though you seem to be looking for a more complicated option : )